# What should be the stuff in formdata in Scrapy for such login page?

Tags: python, scrapy

The login page of the website I want to crawl is like this (form snippet):

```
<table style="margin-top: 1em;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="loginPage:SiteTemplate:siteLogin:loginComponent:loginForm:username" class="stylizedLabel">
                Email</label>
            </td>
            <td><input id="loginPage:SiteTemplate:siteLogin:loginComponent:loginForm:username" 
                type="text" 
                name="loginPage:SiteTemplate:siteLogin:loginComponent:loginForm:username" 
                value="" 
                class="stylizedInput1" 
                aria-describedby="ui-tooltip-0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="loginPage:SiteTemplate:siteLogin:loginComponent:loginForm:password" class="stylizedLabel">
                Password</label>
            </td>
            <td><input id="loginPage:SiteTemplate:siteLogin:loginComponent:loginForm:password" 
                type="password" 
                name="loginPage:SiteTemplate:siteLogin:loginComponent:loginForm:password" 
                value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="loginPage:SiteTemplate:siteLogin:loginComponent:loginForm:loginButton" 
                type="submit" 
                name="loginPage:SiteTemplate:siteLogin:loginComponent:loginForm:loginButton" 
                value="Login" 
                accesskey="" 
                onclick="javascript:captureResponse(this);" 
                style="float:left;" 
                class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" 
                role="button" 
                aria-disabled="false">
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my spider to login and crawl that website:

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'example'

    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com']
    user_key = 'username'
    pwd_key = 'password'
    user_value = 'myusername'
    pwd_value = 'mypassword'

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata = {self.user_key:self.user_value, self.pwd_key: self.pwd_value},
            callback = self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        ...
```

My login try failed and I guess it is because the keys for username and password are not correct in formdata. Then I tried with the following but no good luck still:

```
user_key = 'loginPage:SiteTemplate:siteLogin:loginComponent:loginForm:username'
pwd_key = 'loginPage:SiteTemplate:siteLogin:loginComponent:loginForm:password'
```

What key should I use here in formdata?

Comment: You may want to check in your browser's network tab in developer tools. Maybe some of the data is pre-processed by JavaScript before being sent over POST. Scrapy does not understand JavaScript.

Comment: Do you mean I need to observe the actual network traffic and try to feed Scrapy with the real form data being sent out?

Comment: Something like that yes. JavaScript-driven form submissions require a bit of reverse engineering to be reproducible with Scrapy

Comment: I captured the traffic when login to that website in Chrome via Wireshark. I want to compare the request sent by Chrome and Scrapy during login. That website is HTTPS and I followed this link https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/ to enable SSL decryption in Wireshark (my OS is Ubuntu 16.10), however after putting export SSLKEYLOGFILE=/path/sslkey.log in ~/.bashrc and open Chrome/Firefox with a HTTPS website, there is nothing written into sslkey.log and Wireshark cannot decrypt SSL traffic. Is there any other way to debug Scrapy's request?